# Large Dataset in insert statement using Macro on Text Editor

Tags: sql, macros, notepad++, sublimetext3

Junior Developer here working with Microsoft SQL and Macros in Text Editors

Hey -

I have a dataset here that I have to insert into a table, multiple times.

I have a contacts table, and have to add 4 different contacts into a table on a unique Ident.

So I have 4 insert SQL statements for each unique client ident.

The problem isn't with the insert statement itself, I understand how to write an insert statement.  I do not know how to Macro 300 unique client numbers into a really long insert statement.

```
Insert Into Contacts
FirstName,
LastName,
ClientIdent
```

And I have this dataset of ClientNumbers

```
123
123
123
123
```

How can I macro them into a massive script to insert the same 4 contacts into this table for each unique client number?

I am new at Macros, but was also thinking maybe using a variable in my script and creating a temp table with the client numbers, but I don't know how that would work necessarily because I would have to increase the variable by 4 (in this case) every time and loop it.

How would a senior DBA handle this task?

Thank you

Comment: Sublime macros can only execute commands that modify the buffer, but not in a programmatic/decision making way. You might be able to do something like this with multiple cursors, but otherwise for Sublime you'd likely need some sort of plugin, I think.

Comment: What is your expected result? [Edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55717159/edit)

Answer (score 0):

Try with a regular expressión replacement:

Search: `^(\d+)$`

Replace by: `Insert into table1 (id) values (\1);\r\nInsert into table2 (id) values (\1);\r\nInsert into table3 (id) values (\1);\r\nInsert into table4 (id) values (\1);\r\n`

**note:** change the insert statements to your needs

You have a demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/Gm8Pwn/2/).